# Twitter Login - The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: c#, facebook, twitter, oauth

I am developing an application that uses Facebook and Twitter login as one of the ways to register an account and a few days ago it just suddenly stopped working.
It uses OAuth as the authentication method.
I've checked the keys and they haven't changed, has anyone had experience with this?
I'm now getting this error:

```
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

Comment: Quote: _“Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.”_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for posting without enough information.
But I have reviewed the stack trace and in the method that calls the Token and the TokenSecret from twitters API, the token was actually Null. Once I fixed this by pointing to the token location, it fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Default code snippet.

[image]

Just Replace the above code snippet with the one given below in Startup.Auth.cs class and replace your own Consumer Key and Consumer Secret.

```
app.UseTwitterAuthentication(new TwitterAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ConsumerKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        ConsumerSecret = " XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ",
        BackchannelCertificateValidator = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.CertificateSubjectKeyIdentifierValidator(new[]
        {

          "A5EF0B11CEC04103A34A659048B21CE0572D7D47", // VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
          "0D445C165344C1827E1D20AB25F40163D8BE79A5", // VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
          "7FD365A7C2DDECBBF03009F34339FA02AF333133", // VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary CA - G5
          "39A55D933676616E73A761DFA16A7E59CDE66FAD", // Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
          "‎add53f6680fe66e383cbac3e60922e3b4c412bed", // Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3
          "4eb6d578499b1ccf5f581ead56be3d9b6744a5e5", // VeriSign Class 3 Primary CA - G5
          "5168FF90AF0207753CCCD9656462A212B859723B", // DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server C‎A 
          "B13EC36903F8BF4701D498261A0802EF63642BC3"  // DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
        })
    });
```

Comment: I am getting  the remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure , error recently . I also have above configuration completed still getting error. could you please guide